# Detecting missing characters in ANTLR v4 parser

Tags: antlr4

I need to parse SRGS files written in ABNF format. I need to catch 
missing enclosing double quote character, ex:

```
public $sdsid300035= $<sdsid300101>s number "hee;  // missing enclosing " 
public $sdsid300036= $<sdsid300101>'s number "that's";
```

I've this lexer rule:

```
 DOUBLE_QUOTED_CHARACTERS: '\"' ~(['\"'])*? '\"'
```

It matches valid input, like: "some text". But how to write a rule for detecting and throwing error 
for missing enclosing double quote character like in an example ?

Here is the link to implementation of this rule in ANTLR v3: [ANTLR4 lexer rule with @init block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405713/antlr4-lexer-rule-with-init-block)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a mode to isolate the syntax of what constitutes a valid string:

```
StrStart: '"' -> pushMode(strMode) ;

mode strMode;
ValidStringChar: [a-zA-Z ... ]+ ;
StrEnd:          '"'           -> popMode;
InvalidStrChar1: '>'           -> popMode, type(RAngle);
InvalidStrChar2: ';'           -> popMode, type(Semi);
...
```

When the parser fails to find an alternative in the case of an unterminated string, the Parser's ANTLRErrorStrategy can be used to define how to deal with the error. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550031/how-to-control-error-handling-and-synchronization-in-antlr-4-c-sharp) provides a bit more detail on using error strategies.  Rather that just throwing an error, you have the option to potentially 'warn and recover' from the parser error.

Comment: This will not work for input which have semicolon inside quotes: 
`public $01= "heel;o" ;`

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this using altrenatives, see:

```
doubleQuotedCharacters
 : DOUBLE_QUOTED_CHARACTERS
 | WHITE_SPACES_IN_DOUBLE_QUOTE     {notifyErrorListeners("Illegal empty quotes\"\"!");}
 | MISSING_CLOSING_DOUBLE_QT        {notifyErrorListeners("Missing closing double quote!");}
;

WHITE_SPACES_IN_DOUBLE_QUOTE
: '\"' WS* '\"' -> channel(HIDDEN) 
;                

MISSING_CLOSING_DOUBLE_QT
:   '\"' ~('\"')*?
;

DOUBLE_QUOTED_CHARACTERS
: '\"' ~('\"' | '\n'|'\r' )*? '\"'           
{  setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));}
;
```

I works fine for strings in double quotes which are not divited in multiple lines.